# Doubt about description of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

I have a small doubt. I was solving one algebra question which involved following group.
$G=\{z \in \mathbb C\,|\,z^{n}=1\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb N\}$.
Is this group the entire unit circle? I think yes but not sure. Any hint please.

Comment: Hint if you know about infinite cardinalities: for a fixed $n \in \mathbb N$, how many $z$ are there with $z^n = 1$? How many $z$ are there total in your $G$? How many elements does the unit circle have?

Comment: For fixed n there are n such z. Then |G|= 1+2+3+....(but few z are repeating for some n ..like 1 is there for every n) so what will be correct formula for total elements in G? I got some insight from your hint which is trying to say somewhat that cardinality of G will be countable bt cardinality of unit circle is uncountable( am I right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $G$ is not the entire unit circle. If $r$ is an irrational number, then
$$z=e^{r\pi i}\notin G$$

Answer (score 2):

The unit circle is isomorphic to $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$.

Your group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q / \mathbb Z$, a proper subgroup of $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$.

In both cases, the map is $t \mapsto \exp(t 2\pi i)$.

Answer (score 2):

No, but it's a dense subset of the unit circle. For instance $\cos(1)+i\sin(1)$, which belongs to the unit circle, doesn't belong to $G$.

Answer (score 1):

No, your set is equivalent to:
$$\{e^{2i\pi q}|q\in \Bbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\}$$

if it was $\{z\in \Bbb{C}|z^x=1 \text{ for some } x \in \Bbb{R}\}$, it would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not.

The elements in your group clearly are in the unit circle and are of the form $z=e^{2\pi it}$ where $t\in[0,1)$. But being in $G$ is stronger than that. In fact you have:

\begin{align}
z\in G&\iff \exists n\in\mathbb{N}: z^n=1\\&\iff\exists n\in\mathbb{N}:  e^{2\pi int}=1\\&\iff\exists m,n\in\mathbb{N}:   2\pi int=2\pi im\\&\iff\exists m,n\in\mathbb{N}:   nt=m\\&\iff t\in[0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}
\end{align}